# List Com Ports (Serial Port) in a C# .Net ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, serial-port

Hello I am trying to list all Serial com ports in a ComboBox.
I got this code from an other question, but there are no Ports listed in the comboBox if try. What's wrong? Hope someone can help.

this is the code.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] portNames = SerialPort.GetPortNames();     //<-- Reads all available comPorts
    foreach (var portName in portNames)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(portName);                  //<-- Adds Ports to combobox
    }
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;                        //<-- Selects first entry (convenience purposes)
}
```

I get this Error Messages:

Module was built without symbols. Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll

and

Cannot find or open the PDB file.

Comment: It should work, the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.getportnames(v=vs.110).aspx) says: **Gets an array of serial port names for the current computer.**

Comment: I am trying to get data from a USB scale. The scale is connected and listed as a Serial Converter in Device Manager.
But there is nothing listed in the comboBox...

Comment: Try to call `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` (and only this method, nothing else) in a fresh console project (do not change a single setting there). If you get same exception, then you may be able to tell us error message and show call stack.

Comment: "I don't know why, but I am taking it personally when someone calls .Net as ".Not"."

 I am so sorry! This was a mistake :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Try to call SerialPort.GetPortNames() (and only this method, nothing else) in a fresh console project (do not change a single setting there). If you get same exception, then you may be able to tell us error message and show call stack."

Thank you, The problem was that the code/method was not initialized when form was loading!